# VC++ - change a form element from another form

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli

Using VS 2017 in C++ mode.

I have MyForm.h which works perfectly.  It has a MyForm class that has a bunch of elements and methods, including one called "log()".  It takes some text as input and adds it to a TextBox on the form.

I added another form, called Settings.h.  It also works perfectly, but I would like to be able to use MyForm's log() method to log stuff from the Settings form.

After spending a day reading through insidiously irritating MSDN documentation - or lack thereof, MSDN forum threads which never seem to solve the actual problem, I'm asking for help here.

I know that I should have used C#.  But I wrote like 50% of the project already in C++/CLI and can't really redo everything in C#.

Comment: Try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead describe the problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't call MainForm.log() directly from the Settings class?

Comment: What *is* the problem??

Comment: Here's a VS2017 solution ZIP archive I slapped together in about 10 minutes - it compiles and runs.  The code is in MyForm.h and Settings.h.  I had to comment out the only relevant line in Settings.h (grep for "addlog"), because it wouldn't compile otherwise - that's the issue.  https://filebin.ca/3lGW2TjkzUYY/Project1_20171219_2158.zip

Comment: The issue, in that project file, is that I can use the addlog() function fine as long as I'm in the MyForm.h form, but as soon as I'm in another form (Settings.h for example), or even outside the MyForm class, I cannot call it.

Comment: The goal is to be able to click the button "log something" on the Settings form and have a message added to the logbox control on the MyForm form through the addlog() method of the MyForm form (or any other means really).

Answer (score 0):

There are two related issues here, the first is that your second form will need to obtain an instance of the first somehow. Whether this is through a ctor parameter, a property or otherwise is up to your design.

The second issue is that you need to make sure that whatever methods/properties of the first form that your second needs are either public or that the second form class is a friend of the first.

Comment: Obtaining the instance of the first "somehow" is pretty much the trail I followed for a few hours today to no avail.  Any idea how you would do it?  Here's a test project that compiles in VC2017 and outlines the issue. 
 http://filebin.ca/3lGW2TjkzUYY/Project1_20171219_2158.zip

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: I'm not using VS2017 so I will post pretty much standard C++, which I hope could be of use to you.(I haven't tested this but it should work)

```
 //include MyForm.h //uncomment this if MyForm ^ is declared here   
class Settings{

    private:
     void *mForm; //pointer to the main form -- or MyForm* but with void* we have more flexibility to add different loggers
     //MyForm ^ mForm; //replace void* mForm with this

    public:

        Settings(void *mF) :  mForm(mF){} 
        //Settings(MyForm ^ mF) :  mForm(mF){} 

        void CallMainLog(std::string &str); 

    };
```

In Settings.cpp, add the following

```
#include "MyForm.h"
#include "Settings.h" //remove this include if MyForm ^ is declared in the header

void Settings::CallMainLog(std::string &str){
  ((MyForm*)mForm)->addlog(str); //this 
  //mForm->addLog(str);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't compile at all :-\

Comment: `code` Settings.cpp(4): error C2653: 'Settings': is not a class or namespace name, 1>Settings.cpp(5): error C2065: 'MyForm': undeclared identifier, 1>Settings.cpp(5): error C2059: syntax error: ')'

Comment: Did you add #include Settings.h to cpp file?

Comment: Yes, I did exactly what you outlined.

Comment: Yup.  I even copy/pasted your code instead of retyping.

Comment: If you're using namespaces, try to add them explicitly (e.g mynamespace::MyForm*)

Comment: No worky.  I tried everything, including expliciting namespaces all over.

Comment: I can try my code tomorrow and get back to you (even though I'm pretty certain that it's correct). I don't have a VS compiler though so I can't guarantee that it'll work on your end.

Comment: Just one more thing , is Settings.h included before MyForm.h? If not , swap them in Settings.cpp (some compilers are fussy about this)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that.  If anything, the VS compiler (community edition) if free to download from https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/  :)

Comment: I tried both putting MyForm.h before and after Settings.h (the only other .h included in Settings.cpp).  Didn't change a thing.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that you're running VS in managed (CLI) mode so things like pointers aren't recognized at all (hence C0259 among other things). It's possible to run VS C++ in mixed mode (both native and CLI) but having never worked with VS, I can only refer you to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2012/11/14/ccli-and-mixed-mode-programming/. Alternatively, replace all * occurences with ^ (handles) and stay in managed mode.